# Logout from facebook SDK in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, logout

In my app more than one user can do social media login and share the picture to their timeline.

My question is how to logout the previous user once he used the app? I tried many solutions like below but nothing helped.

**Logout from the Facebook SDK,**

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logOut];
```

**Clear caches**

```
- (void)clearCaches
{
    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies]) {
        NSString *domainName = [cookie domain];
        NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
        if(domainRange.length > 0) {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }

    NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

But nothing helped, Clearing caches are not stable. Most of the times its not clearing caches.

Comment: delete the permission also and try once

Comment: Could you please send me the sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution and now its working fine for me. I use `FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb` to login,

```
login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;
```

Thanks for the help!!